# Problema con Cordova e Ionic

Tags: nodejs, ionic, cordova, ionic-framework

Os cuento un poco.

He instalado Nodejs (LTS) y todo correcto. Puedo ver la versión de node y npm, pero he instalado Cordova e Ionic y al comprobar las versiones me aparece el siguiente error.

***Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'***
o

***Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\ionic\bin\cordova'***

He intentado buscar información pero no he encontrado nada....
He revisado las variables de entorno y las tengo bien, o eso creo....

c:\Program Files\nodejs

Por algún motivo está buscando en ***System32*** y evidentemente ahí no esta la carpeta de  `node_modules`

Trabajo sobre Windows 10 Pro 64bits y la instalación de cordova e ionic la hago asi:

***npm install -g cordova ionic***

¿Puede ayudarme alguien con esto?

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

**Trata de hacer primero la instalación de cada uno de ellos por separado como lo marca la documentación de IONIC.**

```
npm install -g ionic
```

***Por lo que me di cuenta tu comando esta mal según la documentacion de IONIC el comando para instalarlo es este***

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Fuente:

[Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app)

Comment: Gracias Alexis por la repuesta, pero he probado de todas las maneras posibles y nada. No consigo que se instale correctamente ni cordova ni ionic...

Comment: ¿Por que no pruebas borrar todo?

Comment: Y vuelves a instalar todo de 0.

Comment: Reinicia tu computadora sin afectar los archivos, es lo último que te queda.

Comment: Eso creo que también lo he probado, pero lo volveré a intentar.... Lo que ya no sé, es si tendré algún conflico con Visual Studio 2017 tools

Comment: solventado el problema. Por algún motivo raro, el .bat de cordova estaba en System32 y estaba cogiendo de ahí. Lo he borrado y funciona todo ok. Gracias por todo y un saludo.